# Stop automatic image resize in mobile Joomla?

Tags: mobile, joomla, jqtouch

I currently use mobile joomla plugin (http://www.mobilejoomla.com/) to build my mobile website with jqtouch. I can't seem to find a way to stop the automatic resize of the image, even if the options in joomla backend are unchecked, etc. It tries to resize the image and to save it on the remote subfolder "/Resized" and, after, it changes the href of the image to "http:// + ancient address + /Resized/ + filename" ... that is ridiculous.

For example : http: //www.nana.com/image.jpg
would become : http: //image/Resized/image.jpg

T_T'

Answer (score 1):

Set "Image adaptation method: Don't rescale" for each of four device types. Should work.